# Animations one after another in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make 4 animations with jquery. 3 of them will happen at the same time and one will happen after the others have finished. but my code dosn't work

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#div1").fadeIn(5000);
$("#div2").fadeIn(3000);
$("#div3").fadeIn(1500, function(){
$("h3").animate({left: '50%'},3000);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle for the issue.

Comment: What does happen? How does the code not work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem i was having was the h3 was display:hidden which rendered the inside of divs empty so not showing anything. Animate didnt help as it wasnt changing it to display:block.

for fadeIn to work, you need to have jQuery UI included into your project. https://jqueryui.com/

Unsure why I have been down voted for my answer. But have updated code to move header after all have run.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#div1").fadeIn(5000, function() {
    $("h3").animate({ "left": "50%" }, 3000);
  });
  $("#div2").fadeIn(3000);
  $("#div3").fadeIn(1500);
});
```

```css
h3 {position:absolute; }

#div1, #div2, #div3 {
display:none;
position:relative;
height:50px;
}

#div1 { background-color: red; width:100%; }
#div2 { background-color: green; width:100%; }
#div3 { background-color: blue; width:100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="div1"><h3>Wow heading</h3></div>
<div id="div2"><h3>Another heading</h3></div>
<div id="div3"><h3>Last heading</h3></div>
```

Comment: Is this an answer or another question? How do you know what CSS was applied to the elements in the question?

Comment: I didnt, I know how that the divs have to have a display:none; to start with. also I forgot to ask if the user had also included the jquery UI library for the fadeIn to work.

Comment: "the problem I was having" is not a good way to start an answer, it sounds like a question. It's quite common for low-rep users to post new questions as answers, which may be why it was downvoted? Also you're making a lot of guesses about the original code with no evidence to back them up. Once your rep goes up a bit you'll be able to comment to get clarification on these things before posting an answer.

Comment: Thanks miken32 I'll remember that for next time